# where to put setStatusBarHidden:YES if I don't want status bar when using camera

Tags: ios, statusbar, ios-camera

I am new to iOS development. I want the status bar hidden ONLY when I initiate camera so that the camera controls doesn't overlap with the status bar. I found solutions to adding this line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:YES];
```

Where should I put? I tried to add inside my -(IBAction)OpenCamera{} and - (void)viewDidLoad{} but both doesn't work.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest SDK - Xcode 5 - then you might need to add the View-controller status bar appearance boolean to your application .plist

( screen attached ) 
[image]

I'm pretty sure it should be set to **NO** in order for you to be able to dynamically control the appearance. Also you just need:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

I think `withAnimation` is deprecated

Comment: After I set status bar is initially hidden to NO, where should I put that line? I tried again but it doesn't work.

Comment: Its a new plist item:  View-controller status bar appearance

Comment: I added a new plist item called "status bar is initially hidden" and set boolean to NO. Is that what you mean? What about the next step, I mean where should I put [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]; ?

Comment: In your plist on iOS 7 ( Xcode 5 ) the very last item is  View-controller status bar appearance !

Answer (score 1):

for hide status bar in iOS 7 try to add this:

```
- (IBAction)takeCamera {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;

 BOOL cameraIsShow = YES   //custom boolean
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {

  if(cameraIsShow == YES) {
    return YES;
 }
  else return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why preferStatusBarHidden doesn't work, but I get your idea and use a void function instead and it works now =)

Comment: @user2898314 happy to have been of help ;)